# Use custom data type to define new data type in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, types

I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this in Haskell

```
data Word = Det String | Adj String | Noun String | Verb String | Adverb String
data NounPhrase = Noun | Det Noun
```

If I'm going about this wrong, what I am trying to say is - a "Word" is either a "Det", "Adj", "Noun", etc. and a "NounPhrase" is a "Noun" OR a "Det" followed by a "Noun".

When I try to do this I get the error: "Undefined type constructor "Noun""

How can I go about this so it performs as stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing types and value constructors.  When you say

```
data Word = Det String | Adj String | Noun String | Verb String | Adverb String
```

You define the **type** `Word` as being one of a number of forms, for example

```
Det String
```

says that `Det` is a **constructor** that takes a `String` and gives you back a value of type `Word`.  Same goes with `Noun` which is defined to be a *constructor for Words* and not a type.

There are various ways you might encode what you want in Haskell.  By far the simplest is to use

```
data Word = Det String | Adj String | Noun String | Verb String | Adverb String
data NounPhrase = JustNoun String | Compound String String
```

and this is the "learning Haskell" way of doing it.  It is "stringly typed", but is probably sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 4):

When you define an algebraic data type
like

> data MyType = Con1 String | Con2 Int

then `Con1` and `Con2` are *data constructors* which themselves are
functions `Con1 :: String -> MyType` and `Con2 :: Int -> MyType`. 
Your example is having 2 problems:

1. You're using the same data constructor for different types. Since data
   constructors are functions that yield a value of a *specific* type, you can't use
   the same data constructors (`Det` and `Noun`) for `Word` *and* for `NounPhrase`.
   So you need to choose different names for the constructors of
   `NounPhrase`.
2. `Det Noun` does not make sense, since `Noun` is a data
   constructor, whereas the argument of `Det` needs to be a type, e.g., `String`.

See [Constructors in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor) to help clear things up.